# Swift pointer equality always true

Tags: swift

In Swift the following `if` statement is always `true`

```
if self.navigationController?.topViewController === self {
  // always enters the conditional block
}
```

If I write the same code like this

```
if let c = self.navigationController?.topViewController {
  if c === self {
    // do stuff...
  }
}
```

it behaves as expected.

I would assume that the first expression tries to unwrap the left side first and then compare it against `self`, but apparently it doesn't. What is going on here?

Comment: I could not reproduce this with a test. It enters only when both are really identically.

Comment: Funny. If anything, I'd have expected the first test to always fail, not always succeed.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it depends on the class in which you check this condition. If you navigated to a particular viewcontroller there if you check for this condition

```
self.navigationController?.topViewController === self
```

It's always true. Since you're in the topViewController.

But this may fails if you create an instance of someother class and check inside a different class and seek topViewController of navigationController, there it fails.

For instance, Root viewcontroller is UINavigationController -> ViewController -> NextViewController

And inside ViewController.swift

```
 println(" \(self.navigationController?.topViewController === self)")
 // the above line prints "true" since I'm in a topViewController
 var nextVC =  NextViewController()
 println(" \(self.navigationController?.topViewController === nextVC)")
 // the above line prints "false" since nextVC instance is not topViewController of navigation controller.
```

So, the point is even if you unwrap using

```
if let
```

also it just enters into block for self always(if(c === self){}) .